# Error Starting Xamarin Project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, visual-studio, xamarin

I tried to start a Xamarin Project but I got this Error:

```
   Error: this template attempted to load component assembly 
   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizards', Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
   PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f123ed756. For more information on this problem and 
   how to enable this template, please see documentation on Customizing 
   Project Templates.
```

Here is Images of what happened

[Check Image : Trying To Start the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caFhR.jpg)

[Check Image : Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dELcz.jpg)

**I searched the website here but all I found was different problems.**

Comment: Have you got any installation errors in the log for the Xamarin components?

Comment: I got 1 error when I tried to install android SDK, Anyway I got nothing installed in SDKs! Is it needed for Project to run ?